# PostgreSQL: How to recognize data type?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

How to recognize the data type of anyelement inside function?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test1(par1 int,**par2 anyelement**)
RETURNS BOOL
AS $$
DECLARE rc bool := true;
BEGIN
    -- ?
    RETURN rc;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`pg_typeof(any)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-info.html):

```
create or replace function test(par anyelement)
returns text language plpgsql as $$
begin
    return pg_typeof(par)::text;
end $$;

select test(100::int), test('2012-12-12'::date);

  test   | test 
---------+------
 integer | date
(1 row)
```